# IIS 7.5 onwards - Windows login via a web page

Tags: windows, iis, authentication

Is it possible to auto login to IIS using an AD username and password when on the intranet (for example, someone has logged into the AD when logging on to their desktop) AND for them to access the same site when not on the intranet using a login page? Because IIS has to disable anonymous access in order for Windows authentication to work it is not possible to have a login page for users 'off site'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Windows Authentication and you have anonymous access disabled as you say, then AD users should be able to access the site without being prompted to log in, and remote users who have not authenticated with AD will get a Windows dialog box that pops up in the browser and prompts the user to enter their AD credentials.